# Disabling drop down menus on websites

Tags: firefox, browser, usability

Using FireFox, is there a way I can disable drop-down menus on certain websites?

These are the menus that automatically drop down—with the list of options, commands, etc…—when you hover your mouse over them. They really get in my way, distract me from work and are just plain annoying.

I tried to do so with AdBlock it it did not work.

I tried [NoScript](http://noscript.net) better success, menus gone but now I need to figure out a way how I can bring back Flash player (to watch videos) and still keep these menus disabled.

Comment: Turn off JS... Or use a plugin which disables hovers. But your requirement is pretty weird

Comment: @ Mr. Alien: Thanks for pointing in the right direction - to search for a hover disabling plugin. I might be onto something there. As far as the requirements are concerned - I don't see anything weird. Just imagine having an absolutely useless menu unfold and occupy about 10% of your 14-inch screen for about 5 seconds every time you hover your mouse over a fairly large section of the website. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is the [Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remove-it-permanently/) plugin for FireFox.

Once it is installed, right-click on the element that produces a hover-on based menu and run the mouse over the FireFox context menu to the Remove It Permanently command. The element in question will have a red blinking dashed line around it. Click on the command "Remove It Permanently" and the element in question is gone. So is the hover-on menu annoyance.

Comment: Good idea. The new add-on is called "Remove Anything" by RoadrunnerWMC.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the same thing in Chrome because the dropdown menu on Thesaurus.com always blocks the search field and it's annoying.

Here's what worked for me:

Hover over the menu, right-click on the dropdown, select "Inspect" and delete that element, or its parent, in the inspector (see linked image).

The setting reverts back to default if you refresh or open a new tab, just FYI.

I am idiot who stumbled upon this problem and found a solution for myself that I hope will work for you. My apologies if it's poor form to confuse browsers (Firefox vs. Chrome) but I imagine it would work similarly.

![Delete Element]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnS8j.png

Comment: You are a genius.  Thank you so much!  Your issue was *exactly* what brought me here -- the maddening menu at thesaurus.com  I fantasize about telling them their UX really needs to be improved :)